# How to do a Case statement where it looks for a certain character

Tags: bash, shell

I have to do a case statement in my script where the argument can be written as a DIRECTORYNAME or a PATH/DIRECTORYNAME. So, basically create a directory in the current directory or in the path given by the user. I was thinking of doing something like checking if there is "/" in the argument to know if it is a path or not, but I don't know to code that idea in a case statement.
The case statement has to be in that order.

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in #no argument
"") mkdir project
;;
no "/") #don't know how to code it
mkdir $1 
;;
*)#for when argument is path
mkdir $1
;;
esac
```

Different possibilities of script syntax:

```
./case.sh
./case.sh DIRECTORYNAME
./case.sh PATH/DIRECTORYNAME
```

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish the last two cases? They both do the same `mkdir $1`

Comment: If you don't specify a path, it will be created in the current directory automatically.

Comment: @Barmar it is a requirement to do this exercise. It is from a list of exercises provided by my professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases are tested in order, so you need the more specific cases first, and the general case last. So test for `/` first, and then use `*` to match everything else. There isn't a way to match "not /" in a case pattern (unless you enable `bash` extended globbing, which is a nonstandard extension).

```
case "$1" in
    "") mkdir project ;;
    */*) mkdir "$1" ;;
    *) mkdir "./$1" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess it just makes sense to switch case 2 and 3.

Comment: @TheMathAI have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers